# How to configure Application Gateway in Azure for different ports on the same IP address

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-public-ip

I've been working on a project in Azure in which I'd like some help. I have two different VMs running the same project on containers. The first VM has the server of the application and it has a frontend. Also, this VM has a keycloak container. When the user enters the private IP of the server, it redirects to the keycloak login and afterwards it authenticates and redirects to the server frontend. The other VM is the client of the application, and goes through the same process of authenticating with the keycloak that's on the Server VM. I cannot find the proper configuration that allows this process to happen on a public IP, through an Application Gateway. The issue is that when I enter the public IP, the page does not redirect to the keycloak login. I've tried using multi-site configuration on the HTTP settings. I also searched online for answers but I only found situations where people use two VMs, not the same VM for both the frontend and keycloak. I've got two of each: backend pools, http settings, route rules and listeners. Also important, I cannot use a DNS for this matter.

[The backend health returns a 200 status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0rks.png)

So, to sum it up: I need an user to access the public IP frontend of an application that goes through authentication via keycloak. Both are on the same VM, on different ports. This process should happen through an Application Gateway. I'm not a native English speaker, so I apologize if I wrote something wrong or difficult to understand. Any help on this matter would be really appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You should publish also keycloak on the gateway so your users can acces the login page.
More info here : https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy